# Problems with formatting data coming from the html table to the xlsx file in filesaver.js - VueJs

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, filesaver.js

I'm using the Filesaver.js library to export an .xlsx file from a table I own. But I am getting some errors. See below:

**Original table created using VueJs with Quasar Framework:**

[image]

**Generated .xlsx file:**

[image]

**Another case**

[image]

**Generated .xlsx file:**

[image]

My code:

```js
exportTable() {
    let wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(document.querySelector('.q-table'), {
      sheet: "Sheet JS",
    })
    let wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {
      bookType: 'xlsx',
      bookSST: true,
      type: 'binary'
    })

    function s2ab(s) {
      let buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length)
      let view = new Uint8Array(buf)
      for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF
      return buf
    }

    saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)], {
      type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
    }), 'test.xlsx')
```

Why is the format of the characters in the table not being kept when exporting the spreadsheet ?

Is my spreadsheet data not treated as a string?

I'm brazilian. Sorry for bad English (=

Comment: This is Excel trying to be smarter than you. I suspect that even if you export the table as CSV - it may still auto-detect different data type(s) than desired. The best way is to programmatically compose your XLSX by setting the correct formatting for each cell.

Comment: @IVOGELOV There is no possibility to configure the library?

Comment: ... If I put it in CSV format, then it works. But I need it in xlsx format.

Comment: ... With csv I still have the problem with the dates. =/

Comment: Like I said - this is Excel trying to be smarter than you and deducing the type of the cells without explicit format (i.e. those with "Default" format). Therefore you need to programmatically set a relevant format for each cell through the library, just doing `table_to_book` won't suffice (as you already noticed).

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to help me? I've read the documentation a lot, tried a few things, but it wasn't successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of looking for answers, I managed to solve my problem.
More precisely, just use `{raw: true}`. By doing this, the lib no longer formats the data, leaving it in the raw form that comes from HTML. Interestingly, I didn't find this in the documentation.

```js
// import something here
import Vue from 'vue'
import XLSX from 'xlsx'
import {
  saveAs
} from 'file-saver'


// Global Function

const exportExcel = (table) => {

  let wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(table, {
    sheet: "Sheet JS",
    raw: true // Here
  })
  let wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {
    bookType: 'xlsx',
    bookSST: true,
    type: 'binary'
  })

  function s2ab(s) {

    let buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length)
    let view = new Uint8Array(buf)
    for (let i = 0; i != s.length; i++) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF
    return buf
  }

  saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)], {
    type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
  }), 'spreadsheet.xlsx')
}

Vue.prototype.$exportExcel = exportExcel;

// "async" is optional;
// more info on params: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/cli-documentation/boot-files#Anatomy-of-a-boot-file
//export default exportExcel
```

[This link helped me](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/673#ref-commit-9a45c53)